# how to use the custom font icons?

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons, custom-font

I like the icons on this website http://cadence.stylehatch.co/ but I did inspect element it showed me like.

```
content:"\e003"
```

So when I went to this website of custom fonts http://fontcustom.com/ Its hard to understand the usage. It talks about ruby and rails and for me this is all Greek. Is there a better explanation or can someone show me a small demo.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://fontawesome.io/ is a font library for icons. That will get you what you want. You will then use a font like this: `<i class='fa fa-user'></i>` for example.

Comment: my client is adamant on fontcustom and i have tried googling it and still fighting

Comment: fontcustom is for building your own font-library. Unless you need very specific and unique icons, font-awesome or http://fontello.com/ will do just what you need. But, can't argue with the client.